# Git with AWSCodecommit

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codecommit

I have a local git repository.My remote repository is in AWSCodecommit.
Whenever i do push operation it should push my code in remote repository in AWSCodecommit.Basically i am trying to build a pipeline whenever i do push in my loacal it should move code to AWSCodecommit,build and deploy.But in the first step i got stuck.

I tried to clone the repository in using below
$git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/Alpha

It did not copy my repository from AWS to local.Instead i got below error

fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/Alpha/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Answer (score 0):

You need to create IAM user with policy codecommitfull access. Then you also need to create https git credentials. When you clone repo by https, it will ask credentials. Here enter "https git credentials".  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html

Comment: Worth noting that you can also authenticate and connect using SSH.

Comment: Hi,I have a IAM user created and git installed in my windows machine.here i have created one folder called codec and i am going inside that folder ---> right click ---> git bash here and giving command $$git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/Alpha codec.....here its not asking me for any password and throwing above mentioned error.Please let me know if i am missing or doing any wrong steps

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and then realized i was using the aws login credentials

You need to generate a codecommit credential by accessing:

Topbar > My security credentials > AWS CodeCommit credentials > Generate credentials